# Using HashSet from a class in a method of enum class

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum class **Character**, and enum class **Item**:

```
public enum Item
{
COOKIE("cookie"), CRISPS("crisps"), DRINK("drink");    

private String description;    

/**
 * Constructor with description and weight.
 * Pre-condition: description not null.
 */
private Item(String description)
{
    assert description != null : "Item.Item with null description";
    this.description = description;
    sane();
}
```

Character:

```
public enum Character
{
JESS("Jess", 0.5f,Item.SANDWICH), SALLY("Sally",0.5f, Item.CRISPS), 
ANDREW("Andrew" ,0.5f,Item.DRINK), 
ALEX("Alex",0.5f,null),CookieMonster("CookieMonster",1.0f,null),
CookieGiver("CookieGiver",1.0f,null),Player("Player",0.0f,null);

private String description;
private ArrayList<Item> charItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
private float probability;

/**
 * Constructor initialising description,item and probability.
 */
private Character(String desc,float moveProbability,Item items)
{
    description= desc;
    charItems.add(items);
    probability =moveProbability;

}

public void enterRoom(Room r)
{

}
```

The following is a class for creating Room objects

```
  public class Room 
  {
private String description;
private HashMap<Direction, Room> exits;        // stores exits of this room.
private Set<Character> chars;  // stores the characters that are in this 
room.

/**
 * Create a room described "description". Initially, it has
 * no exits. "description" is something like "a kitchen" or
 * "an open court yard".
 * @param description The room's description.
 * Pre-condition: description is not null.
 */
public Room(String description) 
{
    assert description != null : "Room.Room has null description";
    this.description = description;
    exits = new HashMap<Direction, Room>();
    chars = new HashSet<Character>();
    sane();
}
```

How would I write a method in my enum Class such when called then **CookieGiver** gives Item COOKIE to every Character in the Room?

I understand that somehow I need to use the HashSet **chars** but I can't come up with a way to do it.

Comment: Name all enums in a standard way (Upper case)

Comment: First: Rename `Character`. That's an existing class in `java.lang` - then add the method to `Room` (not the `enum`). It's the `Room` that has the state (it contains `Character`s).

Comment: What do you mean by `gives Item COOKIE to every Character in the Room?`. Do you want to mutate the `charItems`?

Comment: charItems is for saving the Items for each character

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I would rather not to put the method in Room

Comment: Do you want to add COOKIE to `charItems` for all characters?

Comment: @user7 yes exactly

Comment: I agree with what @ElliottFrisch has said. But, I would also prefer to keep enums *immutable*.

Comment: If you really want to do it, then you must provide a method in your enum to add to your list

Comment: `public void enterRoom(Room r)
    {
     
    
      if(this.description=="COOKIE")
      {
          receive(Item.COOKIE);
        }
    
}` i wrote this method but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Add a getter to `Room` to get the list of Characters in a Room

```
public Set<Character> getChars() {           
     return chars;                            
}
```

Add a method to the Character enum to add an Item to the list of already held items.

```
private void addItem(Item item) {            
    charItems.add(item);                    
}
```

In your `enterRoom` method, for each character in the Room, call the `addItem`, adding COOKIE to it.

*NOTE:* If this is called multiple times, it'll add multiple COOKIES. If you don't want this, you have to check if COOKIE already exists or use a Set.

```
public void enterRoom(Room r) {              
    for(Character character : r.getChars()) {
        character.addItem(Item.COOKIE);      
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since you want the above strategy to apply only for `CookieGiver`, one way is to make the default logic for `enterRoom` empty and override it for `CookieGiver`.

```
public void enterRoom(Room r) { } //empty / no-op in enum

CookieGiver("CookieGiver", 1.0f, null) {           
@Override                                      
public void enterRoom(Room r) {                
    for (Character character : r.getChars()) { 
        character.addItem(Item.COOKIE);        
    }                                          
}
```

**Option 2:**

You could create a private nested enum holding the strategy on what to do when `enterRoom` is called. Then each character will have one of the strategies against it.

```
public enum Character {
    JESS("Jess", 0.5f, Item.CRISPS, RoomStrategy.NONE),  //when enterRoom is called on this Character, then there is nothing to do
    CookieMonster("CookieMonster", 1.0f, null, RoomStrategy.NONE),
    CookieGiver("CookieGiver", 1.0f, null, RoomStrategy.PROVIDE_COOKIE), //when enterRoom is called on this Character, then invoke the logic corresponding to PROVIDE_COOKIE

    private String description;
    private ArrayList<Item> charItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private float probability;
    private RoomStrategy roomStrategy; //Field to hold the strategy

    /**
     * Constructor initialising description,item and probability.
     */
    private Character(String desc, float moveProbability, Item items, RoomStrategy roomStrategy) {
        description = desc;
        charItems.add(items);
        probability = moveProbability;
        this.roomStrategy = roomStrategy;
    }

    private void addItem(Item item) {
        charItems.add(item);
    }
    public void enterRoom(Room r) {
        roomStrategy.enterRoom(r); //Just delegate to the strategy
    }


    private enum RoomStrategy { //better name needed?
        NONE {
            @Override
            void enterRoom(Room r) {
               //No op
            }
        },
        PROVIDE_COOKIE {
            @Override
            void enterRoom(Room r) {
                for (Character character : r.getChars()) {
                    character.addItem(Item.COOKIE);
                }
            }
        };

        abstract void enterRoom(Room r);
    }
}
```

**Note:** There are better ways to do this as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thats basically what I want the method to do except only Character *CookieGiver* is able to add Item.COOKIE to the charItems of all Characters

Comment: What do you want when `enterRoom` is called for other characters?

Comment: when `enterRoom` is called for other character it shouldn't do anything